# what does a reboot do that sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart does not do re: wifi network availability

Tags: gnome, networkmanager, wireless-networking

Often after resume from suspend network manager (gnome, debian wheezy) finds no networks. Sometimes /etc/init.d/network-manager restart will remedy this problem, but more often restarting network manager does nothing.

After a reboot, networks appear as normal.

Rebooting is (generally) inconvenient. What should one do to recover network-manager functionality beyond restarting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be relevant: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39112

Before suspending the system, GNOME pauses NetworkManager, which causes weird problems with some wireless drivers. A workaround is to reinsert the apropriate module (for example, `modprobe -r ath9k && modprobe ath9k`) after the system wakes up.

- Check `dmesg` for any strange post-resume messages.
- Find out what module your wireless card uses; try to reinsert it.
- Check if `sudo pm-suspend` has the same problem.